# umount or mount possibly corrupting partitions

Tags: mount, btrfs, luks, unmounting

I have installed a new system, using void linux with btrfs + LUKS, everything is working now just need to configure the whole system. I mounted my home from the other system to get some files then unmounted, however upon trying to mount again I got the error from the mount:

```
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

Dmesg doens't show a single error, its like I didn't even tried to mount. Then I decided to mount the root partition and it worked, but after unmounting with the command `umount /mnt` I can't mount it anymore...

Lastly I inserted an old HD that had LVM partition and the same issue: [image]

Here you can see that I mount the lvm, do a ls, then umount and finally try to mount it again.

Now I am stuck with two questions:

1. Is it possible to restore those partitions?
2. Who is the culprit here? Is it mounting a drive that was not using LUKS? Is it the mount? The umount? BRTFS? (If I think about it none of these options makes sense, but without knowing what is causing this how to trust the mount to not destroy your drive?)

Comment: Clearly the mount or umount destroyed critical information: `bash-5.1# e2fsck /dev/sda3
e2fsck 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).
Clear<y>? cancelled!
Journal superblock is corrupt.
Fix<y>? cancelled!
e2fsck: The journal superblock is corrupt while checking journal for /dev/sda3
e2fsck: Cannot proceed with file system check

/dev/sda3: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

/dev/sda3: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********`

Comment: e2fsck is for the ext family of filesystem, not btrfs. Do not use it on a btrfs partition.

Comment: Please add the `dmesg` to your question.